# order of subscriptions in rxjs/Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a reactive form with 2 different directives.  One is a field level directive that subscribes to ngSubmit and controls visibility of field level error messages shown right below the field based on the FormControl's invalid state.  The other is a directive added at the top level, this one also will subscribe to ngSubmit but scroll the document IF invalid fields are hidden from view.

At first I thought I could drive the second directive off the first, meaning that when ngSubmit occurs the field level directive will execute and highlight the error, then the second directive will know the error position (a simple querySelector by the error class) and check if the only errors on the page are hidden from view.

However, it looks like the form level directive ngSubmit subscription fires first at which point there is no error message yet (it is still display:none).  So question - is it possible to somehow enable the first field level directive's ngSubmit subscription to fire before the second higher level one?

The other approach is more involved because it requires the scroll into view directive to work independently, checking the entire Form control graph for invalid controls and finding the associated containing divs and then checking if they are hidden.

Answer (score 2):

> So question - is it possible to somehow enable the first field level
>   directive's ngSubmit subscription to fire before the second higher
>   level one?

I guess you can't control the flow of the ngSubmit subscriptions, but you can have 1 BehaviorSubject variable and subscribe to it the "second ngSubmit" (so basically you won't make any action there first time) and then you will emit (.next(true)) true value from the "first ngSubmit" at the end and then in the subscribe{} block you will execute the desired action you wanted to happen at the end.

Comment: thanks, took a different approach and used the ng-invalid class that Angular tags each element with.